# next button in Eclipse

Tags: android, button

I create an application by eclipse contain 2 activity and i want to go from MainActivity to Activity2  , i create the button but the run didn't work will you help me to fix it

If you need my other code tell me

This is my code 
**for MainActivity  (xml):**

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#6f0fba"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
    android:text="@string/MyNews"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:text="@string/Next" />

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="131dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/Welcome"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="66sp" />
  <View
  android:id="@+id/Button02"/>


  </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity (java):**

```
package com.it332.mynews;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity2.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

});

   }
  }
```

this is my menifest

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.it332.mynews"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="8"
  android:targetSdkVersion="17"
  android:maxSdkVersion="17" />

   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.it332.mynews.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity2"></activity>
  </application>

  </manifest>
```

Comment: Instead of new Intent(view.getContext(), use new Intent(getApplicationContext() and then start this one as :
startActivity(myIntent );

Does it help ?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

and you have to put your Activity2 in android manifest file:

like:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"

            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <activity
            android:name=".Activity2"/>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: have you hsed this way: Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

Comment: my second activity will show you a list of news topic local news sport news ...etc then you choose a topic then press go to take to the newspaper website with the same topic

Answer (score 0):

If you are not expecting any result from the new activity then you should simply start an Activity:-

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity2.class);
view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: my second activity will show you a list of news topic local news sport news ...etc then you choose a topic then press go to take to the newspaper website with the same topic